# creating a web application from java application

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hiii
I already have a desktop application using swings and jframes,i have to create a web application of it,wherein the gui will be of jsp,what can be the most convenient approach to do this,so that i could use my already generated code(linked classes,their objects and functions) in my new project...Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: rewrite the code in jsp or servlet using the similar logic

Comment: Seems you know what you need to do. You're just to lazy to do it.

Comment: You could possibly do that using javaFx. With Swing it seems impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use this directly.
you will have to create new gui for that, 
you can use jsp HTML java code but not j frame in web application.

Comment: yes i have created the gui in jsp...but now i want to implement my original code(functions) on my new gui..how can i do that???

Comment: Do it in servlets rather than jsp so that it will be easier to define and call the functions.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to reuse it the way you described. You will either have to rewrite GUI, or backend, or everything if decoupling one from the other is not possible.

If I desperately needed to reuse the GUI I would have introduced a network (via an [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), say [JAX-WS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services)) in the least contended place (draw class collaboration diagram and partition it in two halves such that GUI is on the left, backend is on the right and the number of lines crossing the cut is minimal (aka [Min Cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut)). The thin GUI can be exposed to the client via [Java Web Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start).